# strange machine code of jmp instruction from nasm compiler

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I had been toying around with NASM and studying how it compiles the asm codes when this situation struck me. I compiled my assembly code with the following command line

```
nasm -f bin crash_test_172.asm -o crash_test -l crash_test_172.lst
```

and its a very simple asm file whose contents are

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

jmp main

Message db "Hello World", 0x0

main:
   cli
   mov ax,cs
   mov ds,ax
   mov es,ax
   mov ss,ax
   sti
```

When I opened the listing file **crash_test_172.lst** I found this rather interesting observation. Here is the content of the listing file.

```
 1                                  bits 16
 2                                  org 0x7c00
 3
 4 00000000 EB0C                    jmp main
 5
 6 00000002 48656C6C6F20576F72-     Message db "Hello World", 0x0
 7 0000000B 6C6400
 8
 9                                  main:
10 0000000E FA                         cli
11 0000000F 8CC8                       mov ax,cs
12 00000011 8ED8                       mov ds,ax
13 00000013 8EC0                       mov es,ax
14 00000015 8ED0                       mov ss,ax
15 00000017 FB                         sti
16
```

If I am not understanding this wrongly, in line 4, the **jmp** instruction points to the byte `0C` whereas, as per the listing, the first instruction in main starts at `0E`.

I also noticed this difference in all the other asm codes which I had been toying with. Surprisingly, every one of them works.

Am I missing something? Can someone help me understand why it is like this? Shouldn't line 4 be `EB0E`; pointing to byte `0E`, the first instruction under main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0xEB is a short, relative jump, so it's the IP after the jump (0x2) plus the offset (0xC) which makes it 0xE.

Comment: Ok. Now that is something I did not know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`EB` is a short relative jump...

> JMP SHORT imm has a maximum range of 128 bytes, since the displacement
>   is specified as only 8 bits, but takes up less code space.

This means that the operand is not an absolute address, but a positive or negative offset from the current address as explained by [500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15398152/31671)
.

Comment: If the displacement is specified using 8 bits, shouldn't the maximum addressing range be 256 bytes? Or am I again understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: @grammar It can be positive or negative, so its range is `-127` to `128` (stored in 2's complement), so it can jump forwards and backwards. :)

Comment: Ah yes! My foolishness of not considering the backward movement :) Thanks for helping with that!

Comment: Actually, it's -128 to 127 - nitpicking, I know :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks, I should have thought about that a bit more :)